# Are these Wordpress tables safe to add indexes to?

Tags: mysql

```
"dbmain"    "wp_usermeta"   "user_id"   "Not indexed"
"dbmain"    "wp_termmeta"   "term_id"   "Not indexed"
"dbmain"    "wp_commentmeta"    "comment_id"    "Not indexed"
"dbmain"    "wp_comments"   "comment_post_ID"   "Not indexed"
"dbmain"    "wp_comments"   "user_id"   "Not indexed"
"dbmain"    "wp_postmeta"   "post_id"   "Not indexed"
"dbmain"    "wp_mf_post_meta"   "post_id"   "Not indexed"
"dbmain"    "wp_term_relationships" "term_taxonomy_id"  "Not indexed"
"dbmain"    "wp_posts"  "guid"  "Not indexed"
"dbmain"    "wp_mf_custom_fields"   "custom_group_id"   "Not indexed"
```

These tables aren't indexed, and I was wondering if it's safe to index them. I think some jobs update and insert rows to some of these tables, but I am thinking to index them. I am not exactly sure how to check if this would boost performance during the peak hours although I suspect it to be the case, because on first inspection I don't really see a lot of UPDATE or INSERT statements after logging all queries. Is this safe and is there some way to check using Wordpress or some other methods?

Comment: `wp_mf_post_meta` and `wp_mf_custom_fields` are not WordPress tables, and WP does add indexes for those tables, it should not be reporting `Not indexed`, unless you've misunderstood the meaning? Are you sure this isn't saying that the table has an index but it hasn't been created yet? Like a house that hasn't been constructed or plans for an unbuilt structure

Comment: Also, adding an index can improve performance, it can also hurt performance if it's done incorrectly or naively, e.g. indexing all columns won't magically yield performance as it defeats the point of an index

Comment: e.g. https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Indexes_5, those tables should already have indexes. How are you getting the output in your code block? I would be highly suspicious of your interpretation

Answer (score 2):

> These tables aren't indexed

These tables ***are*** indexed

For example, the post meta table has these indexes:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Indexes_5

You're more likely to cause issues or reduce performance through bad indexing by adding new indexes. WP already specifies indexes for tables

> "dbmain"    "wp_mf_post_meta"   "post_id"   "Not indexed"
> "dbmain"    "wp_mf_custom_fields"   "custom_group_id"   "Not indexed"

Those are not WordPress tables, you need to ask the plugin authors.

---

What I think has happened here is that you've used a mystery tool that has given you output that has been misinterpreted.

Notice how it does not say "No Index", it says Not indexed. It never claims an index is missing. Also notice that `wp_comments` is listed multiple times. It's more likely that it's showing you indexes that already exist, not tables.